# #break statement not working

Tags: java, velocity, break

I currently need to write some Velocity code, which is new for me. But now, I got a strange error. Instead of letting me my current #foreach loop, a #break statement is displayed as if it was content. Here my code:

```
<div id="posterWall2" class="bloc_home" style="float:left; width:758px; height:368px; margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <p class="titre">Salons Professionels</p>
    <ul class="list_salonspros">
         #if($postersSmall&&$postersSmall.size()>0)
             #foreach($content in $postersSmall)
                 #if ($velocityCount > 4)
                      ##this break is not working!
                      #{break} 
                 #end
                 <li>
                     <a href="$content.manifURL"><div style="width:172px; height:240px;"><img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="$content.afficheURL"></div>
                     </a>
                 </li>
             #end
         #end
    </ul>
    <a class="btnspectacles" href="#">Spectacles</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Not 100% sure, but I think it should be `#break` instead of `#{break}`.</strike>

Also, support for `#break` was only added on version 1.6 ([see here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-612)), so if you are using a previous version I guess it might just print it as content.

Comment: No, in Velocity, the braces are meant to make a statement explicit. But your info was helpful nevertheless. It WAS actually a version issue.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't too sure about the braces, been a long time since I used velocity. But at least I was half right :P

Comment: Francisco Paulo, you can edit the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Due to a previous pom.xml issue, we had 2 Velocity jars in the lib directory of our Tomcat server. The first for version 1.5 and the second for 1.7. And the Tomcat probably loaded the 1.5 version, so it didn't worked properly.

The strange thing is: if I replace the 4 by a 10 in the condition `#if ($velocityCount > 4)`, which I do at another place in my code, it works flawlessly even with the 1.5 version. I still don't understand why...

Comment: Actually, I tried it with 9 and it didn't work either. Could it be related with the number of digits?